# Json Deserialize Nested Objects in Vb (Newtonsoft)

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Basically, I'm trying to get data from the API.

My JSON is :

```
[
  {
    "id": 101,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 91,
        "quantity": 141,
        "size": "12",
        "assigned": false,
        "item": {
          "pk": 27,
          "title": "test title",
          "description": "test description",
          "designer": "designer",
          "category": 4,
          "size": "12,14,16",
          "image": "media/products/indir.jpg",
          "price": 31.0,
          "resin_gr": 31.0
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 92,
        "quantity": 18,
        "size": "14",
        "assigned": false,
        "item": {
          "pk": 26,
          "title": "Bileklik 5",
          "description": "bileklik",
          "designer": "designer",
          "category": 2,
          "size": "12,14,16",
          "image": "media/products/NB00316.png",
          "price": 50.0,
          "resin_gr": 14.0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My Classes are  :

```
 Public Class Orders
        Public Property id As Integer
        Public Property items As IEnumerable(Of OrderItems)
    End Class

    Public Class OrderItems
        Public Property id As Integer
        Public Property quantity As String
        Public Property size As String
        Public Property assigned As String
        Public Property item As List(Of OrderProduct)
    End Class

    Public Class OrderProduct
        Public Property pk As Integer
        Public Property title As String
        Public Property description As String
        Public Property designer As String
        Public Property category As String
        Public Property size As String
        Public Property image As String
        Public Property price As String
        Public Property resin_gr As String
    End Class
```

I'm trying to parse JSON like this :

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of Orders) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IEnumerable(Of Orders))(JSONDATA)
```

I'm getting error on Path '[0].items[0].item.pk', line 1, position 86.

What i tried :

i changed orders.item to list but nothing changed.

what shall i do about this ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MegaPcSlicer.NovaHTTP+OrderProduct]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
Path '[0].items[0].item.pk', line 1, position 86.

Comment: Error clearly states it requires a JSON array, but your document has item as an object: `"item": {`

Comment: @AFriend i actually tried to change "item" : { to "item" : [{.....
but still doesnt work.

Comment: For both OrderItems? and did the error change?

Comment: yes i changed.New error is same only difference is Path '', line 1, position 1. at the end.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect what you are currently testing (and including the actual error in the question).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Public Class Orders
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Items As IEnumerable(Of OrderItems)
End Class
Public Class OrderItems
    Public ID As Integer
    Public quantity As Integer
    Public size As Integer
    Public assigned As Boolean
    Public Item As OrderProduct
End Class
Public Class OrderProduct
    Public pk As Integer
    Public title As String
    Public description As String
    Public designer As String
    Public category As Integer
    Public size As String
    Public image As String
    Public price As Double
    Public resin_gr As Double
End Class
```

Edit: like A Friend commented, This works because you were trying to parse an object as a list here:

```
Public Property item As List(Of OrderProduct)
```

When it needed to be

```
Public Item As OrderProduct
```

Somehow I missed that and solved the issue when I re-created the custom objects for the specified JSON.

Comment: This is bad advice.. The real reason that your answer works is that you changed `List(Of OrderProduct)` to `OrderProduct` to match their JSON.

Comment: I agree with "A Friend"